Combine Multiple Repos into Monorepo
I have 4 NextJS projects (site, admin, auth & ui) I'd like to combine into a monorepo  with the project structure below.
monorepo
├─ apps
   ├─ site
   ├─ admin
   ├─ auth
├─ packages/shared/ui

Do I sequentially add each repo as a remote, fetch/pull/merge --allow-unrelated-histories and remove the remote? How do I move the each app into my apps directory? Or can I just cd into the app directory and pull the repo directly into the app directory?

Yes, it's like you wrote.

This question is similar to: How do you merge two Git repositories?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
